# How to create a class of List of arrays and fetch data in flutter

Tags: arraylist, flutter, error-handling, fetch-api

I'm trying to build a class provider as a list of arrays in order to fetch the data from API, but I'm unable to find a sufficient way thats working in order to fetch the data. I keep getting constant errors. And I cant figure out how to make a list of the Arrays with the class values.

Here is how the code in the API looks(will change the real values just to show an example):

```
{
    "listProduct": [
        {
            "id": 127,
            "title": "String",
            "Date": "2019-10-31T10:03:35",
            "Price": 25.0,
            "category": "Jeep",
            "brand": "مرسيدس",
            "brandModel": "M300",
            "kilometer": 300.0,
            "modelYear": "2010",
            "fuelType": "بنزين",
            "gearType": "اوتوماتك",
            "image": {
                "path": "Upload/UploadCarMain/UploadCarMain-200-200/car.jpeg",
                "name": "car.jpeg"
            },
    ],
}
```

Here is my class provider data which are supposed to be in an array (this has all the values that will be put into the "listProduct"):

```
class AddCar {
  int id;
  String name;
  String city;
  String country;
  String currencyT;
  double price;
  String date;
  String sponsNum;
  String category;
  String company;
  String model;
  String year;
  String engine;
  double distanceCovered;
  String transmission;
  String oilT;
  String outColor;
  String inColor;
  String description;
  File image;
  PlaceLocation location;
  bool isFavorite;

  AddCar({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.city,
    this.country,
    this.currencyT,
    this.price,
    this.date,
    this.sponsNum,
    this.category,
    this.company,
    this.model,
    this.year,
    this.engine,
    this.distanceCovered,
    this.transmission,
    this.oilT,
    this.outColor,
    this.inColor,
    this.description,
    this.image,
    this.location,
    this.isFavorite = false,
  });
}
```

Here is my fetch code (these are the values i need to fetch for my current code displayed):

```
 Future<void> fetchAndSetCars() async {
    const url =
        'My link';

      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      List<AddCar> loadedCars = [];

      extractedData.forEach((carId, carData) {
        loadedCars.add(AddCar(
          id: int.parse(carId),
          name: carData['Title'],
          currencyT: carData['gearType'],
          price: carData['Price'],
          date: carData['Date'],
          model: carData['brandModel'],
          year: carData['modelYear'],
          distanceCovered: carData['kilometer'],
          transmission: carData['gearType'],
          oilT: carData['fuelType'],
          image: File(carData['image']),
        ));
      });
      _cars = loadedCars;
      print(json.decode(response.body));
      notifyListeners();
  }
```

here is where I display my fetch code:

```
class CarArea extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarAreaState createState() => _CarAreaState();
}

class _CarAreaState extends State<CarArea> {
  var _isInit = true;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    if (_isInit) {
      Provider.of<Cars>(context).fetchAndSetCars();
    }
    _isInit = false;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final carsData = Provider.of<Cars>(context);
    final car = carsData.cars;
    return car.isEmpty
        ? Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
              'no cars available',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: ArabicFonts.Tajawal,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                package: 'google_fonts_arabic',
              ),
            )))
        : car.length < 2
            ? ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: car.length = 1,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => CarItem(
                  car[i].id,
                  car[i].image,
                  car[i].name,
                  car[i].model,
                  car[i].currencyT,
                  car[i].price,
                  car[i].distanceCovered,
                  car[i].transmission,
                  car[i].oilT,
                  car[i].year,
                  car[i].date,
                ),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: car.length = 2,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => CarItem(
                  car[i].id,
                  car[i].image,
                  car[i].name,
                  car[i].model,
                  car[i].currencyT,
                  car[i].price,
                  car[i].distanceCovered,
                  car[i].transmission,
                  car[i].oilT,
                  car[i].year,
                  car[i].date,
                ),
              );
  }
}
```

And my CarItem where the code is displayed to the UI:

```
class CarItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final int id;
  final File image;
  final String name;
  final String model;
  final String currencyT;
  final double price;
  final double distanceCovered;
  final String transmission;
  final String oilT;
  final String year;
  final String date;

  CarItem(
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.name,
    this.model,
    this.currencyT,
    this.price,
    this.distanceCovered,
    this.transmission,
    this.oilT,
    this.year,
    this.date,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border(
          bottom: BorderSide(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, width: 2.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 245, 245, 245),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(17.0, 4.0, 17.0, 4.0),
              child: Row(
                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: Row(
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 0, 0, 0),
                          child: Icon(
                            MyFlutterApp.cars,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          AppLocalizations.of(context).itemListCar,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          date.toString(),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 5.0, 0),
                          child: Icon(
                            MyFlutterApp.history,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: image == null
                      ? Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey[200],
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                'No Images provided',
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      : Image.file(
                          image,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                      MyCarDetails.routeName,
                      arguments: id,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(22.0, 5.0, 22.0, 0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom: 5.8,
                          top: 0,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          name,
                        )),
                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                              model,
                              ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            currencyT + price.toStringAsFixed(1),
                           ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Tab(
                            icon: Icon(
                              MyFlutterApp.km,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              distanceCovered.toStringAsFixed(0) + ' KM',
                              ),
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            icon: Icon(
                              MyFlutterApp.motion_vector,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              transmission,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            icon: Icon(
                              MyFlutterApp.fuel_type,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              oilT,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            icon: Icon(
                              MyFlutterApp.general_model,
                              ),
                            child: Text(
                              year,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here is the error i get in my stacktrace:

```
E/flutter (29729): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
E/flutter (29729): listProduct
E/flutter (29729): ^
E/flutter (29729):
E/flutter (29729): #0      int._throwFormatException  (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:131:5)
E/flutter (29729): #1      int._parseRadix  (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:142:16)
E/flutter (29729): #2      int._parse  (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:100:12)
E/flutter (29729): #3      int.parse  (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:63:12)
E/flutter (29729): #4      Cars.fetchAndSetCars.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter_app/providers/car_provider.dart:107
E/flutter (29729): #5      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach  (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter (29729): #6      Cars.fetchAndSetCars 
package:flutter_app/providers/car_provider.dart:105
E/flutter (29729): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29729): #7      _CarAreaState.didChangeDependencies
E/flutter (29729): #8      StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4086
E/flutter (29729): #9      ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3919
E/flutter (29729): #10     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3101
E/flutter (29729): #11     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2904
E/flutter (29729): #12     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3961
E/flutter (29729): #13     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3738
E/flutter (29729): #14     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3924
E/flutter (29729): #15     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3919
E/flutter (29729): #16     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3101
E/flutter (29729): #17     Element.updateChild
E/flutter (29729): #18     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3961
E/flutter (29729): #19     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3738
E/flutter (29729): #20     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3924
E/flutter (29729): #21     StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4088
E/flutter (29729): #22     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3919
E/flutter (29729): #23     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3101
E/flutter (29729): #24     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5233
E/flutter (29729): #25     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3101
E/flutter (29729): #26     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2904
E/flutter (29729): #27     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
E/flutter (29729): #28     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3101
E/flutter (29729): #29     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2904
E/flutter (29729): #30     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5127
E/flutter (29729): #31     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3101
E/flutter (29729): #32     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2904
E/flutter (29729): #33     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3961
E/flutter (29729): #34     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3738
E/flutter (29729): #35     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3924
E/flutter (29729): #36     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3919
E/flutter (29729): #37     Element.inflateWidget
E/flutter (29729): #38     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2904
E/flutter (29729): #39     ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3961
E/flutter (29729): #40     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3738
E/flutter (29729): #41     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3924
E/flutter (29729): #42     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3919
E/flutter (29729): #43     ParentDataElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4314
E/flutter (29729): #44     Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3101
E/flutter (29729): #45     Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2904
E/flutter (29729): #46     Componen
```

print gave me this:

```
{listProduct: [{id: 127, Title: car -en, Date: 2019-10-31T10:03:35, Price: 25.0, category: car child 2, categoryId: 8, status: 1, brandId: 1, brand: mercedes, brandModelId: 6, brandModel: M300, kilometer: 300.0, modelYearId: 2, modelYear: 2010, fuelType: benz, carFeatureFuelId: 3, gearType: automatic, carFeatureGearId: 2, image: {path: Upload/UploadCarMain/UploadCarMain-200-200/carCar127.jpeg, name: carCar127.jpeg}, vendorId: 2}, {id: 44, Title: null, Date: 2019-10-26T09:16:23.0265211, Price: 3454.0, category: car child 1, categoryId: 7, status: 1, brandId: 2, brand: BM, brandModelId: 7, brandModel: BM X5, kilometer: 345.0, modelYearId: 2, modelYear: 2010, fuelType: dezil, carFeatureFuelId: 4, gearType: normal, carFeatureGearId: 1, image: {path: Upload/UploadCarMain/UploadCarMain-200-200/1Car44.jpg, name: 1Car44.jpg}, vendorId: 1}, {id: 43, Title: null, Date: 2019-10-25T09:40:46.4631028, Price: 25.0, category: car child 1, categoryId: 7, status: 1, brandId: 1, brand: mercedes, brandModelId: 6,
```

after printing loadedCars:

```
[{id: 127, Title: car -en, Date: 2019-10-31T10:03:35, Price: 25.0, category: car child 2, categoryId: 8, status: 1, brandId: 1, brand: mercedes, brandModelId: 6, brandModel: M300, kilometer: 300.0, modelYearId: 2, modelYear: 2010, fuelType: benz, carFeatureFuelId: 3, gearType: automatic, carFeatureGearId: 2, image: {path: Upload/UploadCarMain/UploadCarMain-200-200/carCar127.jpeg, name: carCar127.jpeg}, vendorId: 2}, {id: 44, Title: null, Date: 2019-10-26T09:16:23.0265211, Price: 3454.0, category: car child 1, categoryId: 7, status: 1, brandId: 2, brand: BM, brandModelId: 7, brandModel: BM X5, kilometer: 345.0, modelYearId: 2, modelYear: 2010, fuelType: dezil, carFeatureFuelId: 4, gearType: normal, carFeatureGearId: 1, image: {path: Upload/UploadCarMain/UploadCarMain-200-200/1Car44.jpg, name: 1Car44.jpg}, vendorId: 1}, {id: 43, Title: null, Date: 2019-10-25T09:40:46.4631028, Price: 25.0, category: car child 1, categoryId: 7, status: 1, brandId: 1, brand: mercedes, brandModelId: 6, brandModel
```

Comment: I think you didn't have the access of your `listProduct` JSONArray. you have to first access that and then you have to fill the data in the DATA class

Comment: Yea im aware of that but how do I get access to it? do I need to turn my `AddCar` class into an array? and if so how do I display that data ive tried multiple ways and none worked

Comment: first of all print the `extractedData` for me and give the result what you have.

Comment: Just edited my post chech at the bottom print part

Comment: Okay i will answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to access the `listProduct` by this.

```
final response = await http.get(url);
final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
List loadedCars = extractedData['listProduct'];
for(var i in loadedCars) {
    _cars.add(AddCar(
      id: i["id"],
      name: i['Title'],
      currencyT: i['gearType'],
      price: i['Price'],
      date: i['Date'],
      model: i['brandModel'],
      year: i['modelYear'],
      distanceCovered: i['kilometer'],
      transmission: i['gearType'],
      oilT: i['fuelType'],
      image: File(i['image']),
    ));
}
```

This way you will create a data arraylist and in view you have to access the 
that arraylist `_cars`.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I got the following error have you got an Idea of what its indicating at? `Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'iterator' was called on null.`

Comment: can you please just print the `loadedCars` list?

Comment: sorry that was my bad I forgot to change the "listProduct" to the real value and not custome one in this example. but after fixing it a different error appeared not sure if its related to this question tho `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

Comment: haven't you removed the `as Map<String, dynamic>`?

Comment: I removed it yes. I printed the loadedCars for you check the code again

Comment: did you have print it on a last print part?

Comment: I think the error is with the "image" pathing. your way has worked thank you so much! ill try and solve the other error now apprevciate it a lot!